# Fixed (inside) front disk brake adjustment

Tags: disc-brake

I got a new bike for Christmas (12-25-12) and it is a *VICTORY* VEGASJACKPOT w/medium-travel front fork and full suspension. The front disc brake rubs against the inside pad (the one on the fork side of the rotor) and I have no idea how to adjust it.
Thank you! 
P.S. This bike is totally fine otherwise, with a nice low price too!!

Comment: When I search for the brand and name of your bike, I only find motorcycles. This board is about bicycles. So maybe your question is wrong here.

Comment: This is a mountain bike with Shimano parts: http://www.amazon.com/Victory-Jackpot-Dual-Suspension-Mountain-26-Inch/dp/B001DHGHNI.

Comment: I'm just learning MTB's, but this looks to be a good video to supplement Mikes answer below: http://youtu.be/XAUTCZ3gIyU

Comment: It is a Walmart Site-to-store bicycle. P.S. Ken H, this *is* my bike.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an entry level bike. As few specifications are available I'll give you some generic adjustments. You question is a bit confusing as the pad closest to the fork is called the outside or outboard pad, the pad that is closest to the center of the wheel is the inside or inboard pad. If the rotor drags in only one spot you need to tweek the rotor. I use an adjustable wrench closed tight on the rotor. Gently push just enough to feel movement, then recheck. On cable operated disc brakes the outside pad is pushed into the rotor by the caliper piston. The inside pad does not move when the lever is pulled. The outside pad deflects the rotor slightly, just enough to make it rub the rotor. The initial adjustment is made by loosening the caliper mounting bolts. Center the caliper so there is an equal gap on both sides, tighten the screws. If you can't see a gap between the rotor and pads they may be set too tight. If you look through the spokes you may see an adjusting bolt on the backside of the caliper Rotating the screw clockwise will move the inside pad closer to the rotor, counterclockwise moves it away from the rotor.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to find the adjusting bolt. On the inside (got my jargon right, near the wheel) brake (front), I do see 2 spots for allen keys, but they adjust that one (inside), not the outboard pad. Maybe you could check a picture?

Comment: Also, my bike is cable-operated from what I can see. P.S. Please vote me up or give me reputation or whatever so that I can vote up your question.

Comment: A-HA! I got it! I screw this thingy (spelling of this word is arguable, but this is what Firefox says is right) by the brake lever _in_, and it gets less loose! I now get it conceptually _and_ logically! Yaaaay!! Just loosen the cable!!